# How to Calculate Small Order

Tags: real-analysis, approximation, approximation-theory

## Question

Let $c$ be constant. As $x \to 0$,
$$
f = cx^2 + o(x^2).
$$

Then,
$$
f^2 = c^2 x^4 + o(x^4).
$$

## What I think

\begin{align*}
f^2 &= c^2 x^4 + 2cx^2 o(x^2) + o(x^4) \\
&= c^2 x^4 + o(x) \cdot o(x^2) + o(x^4) \\
&= c^2 x^4 + o(x^3) + o(x^4) \\
&= c^2 x^4 + o(x^3).?
\end{align*}

Why is it different?

Comment: You shouldn't weaken $x^2$ to $o(x)$.

Comment: $x^2o(x^2)=o(x^4)$ (try to show)

Comment: I know your idea(theorem).

Comment: In that case, $2c\cdot o(x^4) + o(x^4) = o(x^3) + o(x^4)=o(x^3)$; same result, isn’t it?

Comment: Why do you want to keep weakening $o(x^4)$ to $o(x^3)$?